# Safari is more forgiving locally than remotely with malformed HTML. Why?

Tags: security, safari

I ran into a curious issue today. We have a web page that hides the `body` via CSS and then there's a bit of JavaScript that sets the `body` to `display: block` to show it. (This is part of some iFrame busting logic we are required to add).

We were having issues on one page but only in Safari. In taking a look at things, I found that the culprit was that an include file was being called that contained its own `body` tag so we were ending up with malformed HTML with a `body` tag nested within the pages existing `body` tag.

Since the JS was looking for the first `body` tag the content we actually wanted to show was never shown, since it was wrapped with the second `body` tag.

I assume Firefox was just forgiving of the HTML and ignored the second `body` tag. Safari didn't do this when we looked at the page on the server.

However, if I grab the file and run it locally, Safari does tell me:

> Extra `<body>` encountered. Migrating attributes back to the original `<body>` element and ignoring the tag.

I'm curious as to why Safari might have adopted this 'policy' of ignoring bad HTML locally but not from a server. If it matters, it is an https site we're hitting. Perhaps Safari is being wise and trying to avoid any potential security issues with allowing bad HTML?